# Return only a few keys in a dictionary? Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary with values attached. I am able to get all keys. I have done searching around and a lot of people are saying to put the keys in a list, However I need the values attached to that key and the values must stay the same.

```
mydict = {'Car':'BMW','Speed':'kph','Range':33}
for keys in mydict:
    print(keys)
```

What I am after is any two of the keys and their values to be printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what are you looking for.
You want to print values also? Go for

```
mydict = {'Car':'BMW','Speed':'kph','Range':33}
for keys in mydict:
    print(keys,":",mydict[keys])
```

You want just print 2 of them?

```
mydict = {'Car':'BMW','Speed':'kph','Range':33}
from itertools import islice
def take(n, iterable):   
    return list(islice(iterable, n))

n_items = take(2, mydict.iteritems())
print(n_items)
```

You'll need itertools from pip tho.

Answer (score 1):

Well, even if you put them in a list, you can still get the values:

```
mydict = {'Car':'BMW','Speed':'kph','Range':33}
keys = list(mydict)
for key in keys:
    print(mydict[keys])
```

If you want only two keys you can do:

```
keys = keys[:2]
```

And if you want a new dictionary using only those two keys:

```
mynewdict = {k:v for k,v in mydict.items() if k in keys}
```

And probably the shortest:

```
for key in list(mydict)[:2]:
    print(key, mydict[key])
```